# Utilizing City and County Data Together

Tags: tableau-api

I have a bunch of people related data where the only geographical field is "City, State":

```
Client          |   Location        |   Salesperson
Company A       |   Albany, NY      |   Joe
Company B       |   Atlanta, GA     |   Steve
Company C       |   Baltimore, MD   |   Lisa
Company D       |   Wichita, KS     |   Suzy
Company E       |   Portland, OR    |   Steve
Company F       |   Spokane, WA     |   Suzy
Company G       |   Mobile, AL      |   Joe
Company H       |   Elizabeth, NJ   |   Lisa
```

That third row is the salesperson. The problem is, each territory is defined by customized regions based off of counties. For example, the New York metropolitan area is defined by [the counties listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_metropolitan_area#Definitions).

So a couple questions. First, how do I add in that data to Tableau (where I have all cities and counties). The second is, how can I create somewhere say, I wanted to see performance based on salesperson by region. So like, say I wanted a breakdown of how each sales person performed in the New York Metro area. That would involve me evaluating based on the cities within a customized region based off counties. So in the above table, Lisa's sale in Elizabeth, NJ would be credited as a sale in the New York Metro area.

You'll have to forgive me, I'm a bit of a neophyte in Tableau.

Comment: Do you already have the dataset with each city and its associated county?  If not, this should help: 
https://simplemaps.com/static/data/us-cities/uscitiesv1.3.csv

Comment: A quick solution would be to group the specific locations into the defined sales areas using Tableau's ability group categories into higher units.